# Check a collection of SIDs for membership in a given group

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a collection of SID values and need to display if they are in a given group. I know I can do that with CheckTokenMembership, if I had a token handle. How do I get a token handle from an SID in Windows?

Comment: you need first convert *SID* to user name via `LookupAccountSid` and than call `NetUserGetGroups` or `NetUserGetLocalGroups`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `LookupAccountSid` to get the account for the SID
2. Use `NetUserGetGroups` to get all groups this account is a member of.
    **EDIT** Note from eryksun: *Check target group's SID first. If it's SidTypeGroup, call NetUserGetGroups. If it's SidTypeAlias, call NetUserGetLocalGroups (AKA aliases, such as "BUILTIN\Administrators")*
3. Use `LookupAccountName` to get the SIDs of the group.
4. Check if account SID (step 1) is member of the SID collection (step 3). Use `EqualSid` function.

You find appropriate old code one the old win32.mvps.org pages. Sadly the page is gone. But Wayback machine helps. Here a link to the old [fksec samples](https://web.archive.org/web/20101129205030/http://win32.mvps.org:80/)

You find an easy to use sid class there. It also provides `sid::MemberOf` and `sid::Members` functions. The code isn't my style but it works.

Comment: The second step should be preceded by getting the target group's SID and type. If it's `SidTypeGroup`, call `NetUserGetGroups`. If it's `SidTypeAlias`, call `NetUserGetLocalGroups` (AKA aliases, such as "BUILTIN\Administrators"). Then get the SID of each group and compare it to the target group SID.

Comment: You are right! Changed my answer. Thanks for the comment!